# Python request - I started programming

Tags: python, request

My request, I started programming in Python and I got this request to do it.

Direct me how to do it?

Write a program that takes from the user the length of two sides of the triangle and the angle between them (in degrees) and calculates (and displays) on this basis the length of the third side (theorem of cosines), the field (Heron formula or formula for height) and the perimeter of the triangle.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site isn't a code writing service. Please take a moment to re-read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

As i new programmer, i know how to do that the program take two numbers and i have problem how this program should take etc 90 degree angle

> a = float(input("first side"))
>   b = float(input("second side"))
>   x = float(input("degree angle"))

how program can compute third side (c)?

Answer (score 0):

Like this ..

```
import math

#taking input from user
a = float(input('Enter first side of triangle: '))
b = float(input('Enter second side of triangle: '))
alpha = float(input('Enter angle between a and b: '))

#finding third side of triangle
c = math.sqrt((math.pow(a, 2)+math.pow(b, 2)) - 2*a*b*(math.cos(alpha)))
print('third side of triangle is: ', c)

#calculate perimeter
s = ((a+b+c)/2)

print('perimeter of triangle is: ', s)

#calculate area
area = math.sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))

print('Area of triangle is: ', area)
```